# fix accuracy in python tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

Background: We try to produce a model that will predict whether a case is happening or not, based on data numbers in rnn model
The problem: We reached a situation in which the LOSS decreases but the accuracy remains at 0.5

```
tf.initialize_all_variables()
ops.reset_default_graph()
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()




np_labels = np.array(labels)
np_labels = np_labels.reshape([np_labels.shape[0], 1])
print([np_labels.shape[0], 1])

############################ modle ############
cellsize = 100
possible_chars = 1
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 91, 10])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])

lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(cellsize, forget_bias=0.0)
output, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)

output = tf.transpose(output, [1, 0, 2])
last = output[-1]

W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([cellsize, possible_chars], stddev=0.1))
b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1))

z = tf.matmul(last, W) + b
res = tf.nn.sigmoid(z)

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y * tf.log(res), reduction_indices=[1]))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(cross_entropy)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
correct_prediction = tf.greater(res, 0.1)
correct = tf.equal(correct_prediction, tf.equal(y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, tf.float32))

############################ startTheTrain ################


     num_of_epochs = 10
    for ephoch in range(num_of_epochs):
    _, loss = sess.run([train_step, cross_entropy], feed_dict={x: fvecs,   y:np_labels})          
    a = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: fvecs, y: np_labels})  #

    print("step %d, loss: %g, training accuracy %g" % (ephoch, loss, a))
```

After I run the code I get this output:

```
step 0, loss: 0.338716, training accuracy 0.5
step 1, loss: 0.130198, training accuracy 0.5

step 8, loss: 0.0502876, training accuracy 0.5
step 9, loss: 0.0468232, training accuracy 0.5
```

I am trying to fix the code so that accuracy  it will work

Comment: Did you try to change number of hidden layers in deep learning algorithm ?

Comment: Yes, but it did not affect

Comment: Then, There might be issue at the way you train the model.